# setMultiChoiceItems() doesn't shows items

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Im using a **DialogFragment** to show a Dialog with a multi choice items, it shows the Dialog but without the items, there is no checkboxes to select.

This is how i invoke the dialog:

```
    botAddMedicacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment fragAddMedic = new AnadirMedicacionFragment();
            fragAddMedic.show(getFragmentManager(), "addMedicacion");
        }
    });
```

And this is the **AnadirMedicacionFragment** code:

```
    final CharSequence[] items={".NET","J2EE","PHP"};

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    medicSelec = new ArrayList();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.anadir_medicacion);


    // elementos de la lista
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                medicSelec.add(which);
            } else if (medicSelec.contains(which)) {
                medicSelec.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
            }

        }
    });

    // boton ok
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.anadir, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    // boton cancelar
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

The item list is passed in builder.setMultiChoiceItems(**items**, null[...]

[image: dialog fragment multi choose]

It seems it works, but there are no checkboxes or list.

Comment: Does something appear if you click on one of the items?

Comment: I think you mean the positive and negative buttons, if i click one of the buttons it disappears the dialog.

Comment: I do not mean the buttons, I mean the text itself. "Andair medicacion".

Comment: No, the "Añadir medicacion" it's just the title of the dialog.

Comment: Ahhh, so the items aren't showing either. That wasn't clear.

Comment: ojetehandler was here. `.setMessage()` can't be used with multichoice items

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `setMessage` and a `setMultiChoiceListener`. You can only have one of them. Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.anadir_medicacion);
```

Comment: I changed setMessage to setTitle and it works, there was the problem. Thanks PearsonArtPhoto!